# Count the word but ignore when it has a word with first letter capitalized before

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to determine whether the word "McDonald" is in the cell. However, I wish to ignore the case where the word before "McDonald" has a first captilized letter like 'Kevin McDonald'. Any suggestion how to get it right through regex in a pandas dataframe?

```
data = {'text':["Kevin McDonald has bought a burger.", 
                "The best burger in McDonald is cheeze buger."]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
long_list = ['McDonald', 'Five Guys']

# matching any of the words
pattern = r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(long_list))

df['count'] = df.text.str.count(pattern)
```

```
                                           text
0           Kevin McDonald has bought a burger.
1  The best burger in McDonald is cheeze buger.
```

Expected output:

```
                                           text  count
0           Kevin McDonald has bought a burger.      0
1  The best burger in McDonald is cheeze buger.      1
```

Comment: You can find a regex for this particular pattern, but if you are trying to distinguish person names vs. other proper names, use something more appropriate: Work with the list of words/tokens, or better yet, load up a named entity recognizer (NER)

Comment: You mean applying NER to remove "Kevin McDonald" like cells? Hmm. That's a pretty interesting idea. @alexis

Comment: More or less. You don't explain the reason you are trying to make this distinction, but whatever your goal is, you will probably need more rules in the near future and there are better approaches for that than whole-sentence regexes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, the goal is not to match when there is a preceding word that is capitalized. Checking that there is a non capitalized word before would remove many legitimate possibilities.

Here is a regex that works for a few more possibilities (start of sentence, non word before):

```
regex = '|'.join(fr'(?:\b[^A-Z]\S*\s+|[^\w\s] ?|^){i}' for i in long_list)
df['count'] = df['text'].str.count(regex)
```

example:

```
                                           text  count
0           Kevin McDonald has bought a burger.      0
1  The best burger in McDonald is cheeze buger.      1
2                       McDonald's restaurants.      1
3                 Blah. McDonald's restaurants.      1
```

You can test and understand the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/M8nKfw/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this pattern:

```
pattern = r'\b[a-z].*?\b {}'.format('|'.join(long_list))

df['count'] = df.text.str.count(pattern)
```